# Android : Dynamic View Pager Just showing Changes in the first fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I m very much new to android, What i m trying is to dynamically create swipe tabs and add swipable pages i.e Fragments to a view pager.
I saw some of the tutorials and tried a few things out.
I m pasting the code for the same below.

**this is the fragment class which I m adding to the viewpager**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import technovators.mahendraprophecy.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.app.Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    static String category;

    public SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static final SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT newInstance(String message)

    {
        category=message;
        SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT f = new SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),category,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cat)).setText(category);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_list_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

**this is the main fragment which has the tabs and a viewpager attached to it**

```
public class LATEST_NEWSLETTERS extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    MaterialTabs subTabs;
    ViewPager subPager;
    private String[] titles = new String[]{"Weekly Newsletter", "Market News & Updates", "Day Trade Flash News"};
    ArrayList<String> headers,header_colors,category_ids;
    List<Fragment> fList;
    public LATEST_NEWSLETTERS()
    {

    }

    public LATEST_NEWSLETTERS(String categoryData)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(categoryData);
            JSONArray array=object.getJSONArray("categories");
            headers=new ArrayList<>();
            header_colors=new ArrayList<>();
            category_ids=new ArrayList<>();
            fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                object=array.getJSONObject(i);
                headers.add(object.getString("name"));
                header_colors.add(object.getString("bgcolor"));
                category_ids.add(object.getString("cat_id"));
                fList.add(SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT.newInstance(object.getString("cat_id")));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void setupTabs()
    {
        subTabs= (MaterialTabs) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.subTabs);
        subPager= (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.subPager);
        latestNewLetterAdapter adapter=new latestNewLetterAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        subPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        subTabs.setViewPager(subPager);
        subTabs.setIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor(header_colors.get(0)));
        subTabs.setTextColorSelected(Color.parseColor(header_colors.get(0)));

        subPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                subTabs.setIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor(header_colors.get(position)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfragment_latest_newsletters, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setupTabs();
    }


    class latestNewLetterAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements MaterialTabs.CustomTabProvider
    {
        public latestNewLetterAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return fList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

/*
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            String x=headers.get(position);
            if(x.contains("&"))
            {
              x=x.replaceAll("&amp;"," & ");
            }
            return x;
        }
*/
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return headers.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            TextView header=new TextView(getActivity());
            String x=headers.get(i);
            if(x.contains("&"))
            {
                x=x.replaceAll("&amp;"," & ");
            }
            header.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(header_colors.get(i)));
            header.setText(x);
            header.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            return header;
        }
    }
}
```

I m retrieving json (json-array) data from the server usin a Async Task in the previous activity and passing it to this fragement in form of a string in the constructor.

The Adapter fills the tabs with Titles and gets the items from the fragment list created in the custom constructor of the fragment class, i have also read that using a custom constructor is not a good practice, I will be implementing interfaces for the same purpose but that's not the major issue here.

**Problem**

If you see, I m passing category id to each fragment of the viewpager and it should set the respective category in each of the fragment but what happens here is it just setting the id in the first fragment or call it the first tab rest all fragments just show the text "category id" and not the category which is to be set instead when i swipe to the second fragement the cateory id of second fragment is set in the first one, when i swipe to the third fragment the category id of the third one is set to the first

So basically all actions are taking place in the first fragment only instead of all.

Please help me where m i wrong ?
I need dynamic pages to be added as the no of categories are varying every time and accordingly the number of pages should be added to the view pager and a list will be loaded in each page corresponding to the category id of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SUB_LIST_FRAGMENT, try moving your code from onActivityCreated to onCreateView. The result should look something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_list_fragment, container, false);
    ((TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.cat)).setText(category);
}
```

onActivityCreated probably only gets called once while onCreateView will be called each time a new fragment is created in your viewpager.

Comment: @Hasslam Let me Just try